# IdentityUtil Class Definition Not Found Error in WSO2 API Manager 4.1 startup

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I am trying to run the wso2am-4.1.0 on Centos 7. And it cannot deploy these three webapps as follow.

- authenticationendpoint
- oauth2
- accountrecoveryendpoint

And it throws the Class `org/wso2/carbon/identity/core/util/IdentityUtil` not found error.

```
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.322.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /root/wso2am-4.1.0
Using Java memory options: -Xms256m -Xmx1024m
...

[2022-05-08 12:34:16,137]  INFO - EventProcessorDeployer Execution plan is deployed successfully and in active state  : carbon.super_sub_Unauthenticated
[2022-05-08 12:34:16,599] ERROR - [/accountrecoveryendpoint] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.endpoint.util.listener.IdentityManagementEndpointContextListener]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/wso2/carbon/identity/core/util/IdentityUtil
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.endpoint.util.IdentityManagementServiceUtil.init(IdentityManagementServiceUtil.java:130) ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.endpoint.util_5.18.248.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.endpoint.util.listener.IdentityManagementEndpointContextListener.contextInitialized(IdentityManagementEndpointContextListener.java:34) ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.endpoint.util_5.18.248.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4768) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat.addWebApp(CarbonTomcat.java:303) ~[?:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat.addWebApp(CarbonTomcat.java:209) ~[?:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.handleWebappDeployment(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:255) ~[org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt_4.11.3.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.handleExplodedWebappDeployment(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:243) ~[org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt_4.11.3.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.handleHotDeployment(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:173) ~[org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt_4.11.3.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.deploy(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:140) ~[org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt_4.11.3.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.AbstractWebappDeployer.deployThisWebApp(AbstractWebappDeployer.java:224) ~[org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt_4.11.3.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.AbstractWebappDeployer.deploy(AbstractWebappDeployer.java:114) ~[org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt_4.11.3.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.deployer.WebappDeployer.deploy(WebappDeployer.java:42) ~[org.wso2.carbon.webapp.deployer_4.11.3.jar:?]
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v80.jar:?]
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v80.jar:?]
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:153) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v80.jar:?]
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v80.jar:?]
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v80.jar:?]
        at org.apache.synapse.Axis2SynapseController.deployMediatorExtensions(Axis2SynapseController.java:785) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
        at org.apache.synapse.Axis2SynapseController.createSynapseEnvironment(Axis2SynapseController.java:403) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
        at org.apache.synapse.ServerManager.start(ServerManager.java:187) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
        at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.initESB(ServiceBusInitializer.java:371) ~[org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer_4.7.131.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.activate(ServiceBusInitializer.java:170) ~[org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer_4.7.131.jar:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_322]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_322]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_322]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_322]
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.persistence.service.InboundEndpointPersistenceServiceDSComponent.activate(InboundEndpointPersistenceServiceDSComponent.java:50) ~[org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.persistence_4.7.131.jar:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_322]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_322]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_322]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_322]
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:529) ~[org.wso2.carbon.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.removePendingItem(CarbonServerManager.java:305) ~[org.wso2.carbon.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.bundleChanged(PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.java:118) ~[org.wso2.carbon.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:973) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityUtil
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.loader.CarbonWebappClassLoader.loadClass(CarbonWebappClassLoader.java:195) ~[org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt_4.11.3.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1215) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
        ... 76 more
[2022-05-08 12:34:16,599] ERROR - StandardContext One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
[2022-05-08 12:34:16,600] ERROR - StandardContext Context [/accountrecoveryendpoint] startup failed due to previous errors
[2022-05-08 12:34:16,692] ERROR - CarbonTomcat Cannot stop context
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_stop]) for component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/accountrecoveryendpoint]] in state [DESTROYED]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:430) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:244) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat.addWebApp(CarbonTomcat.java:321) ~[?:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat.addWebApp(CarbonTomcat.java:209) ~[?:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.handleWebappDeployment(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:255) ~[org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt_4.11.3.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.handleExplodedWebappDeployment(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:243) ~[org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt_4.11.3.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.handleHotDeployment(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:173) ~[org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt_4.11.3.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.deploy(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:140) ~[org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt_4.11.3.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.AbstractWebappDeployer.deployThisWebApp(AbstractWebappDeployer.java:224) ~[org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt_4.11.3.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.AbstractWebappDeployer.deploy(AbstractWebappDeployer.java:114) ~[org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt_4.11.3.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.deployer.WebappDeployer.deploy(WebappDeployer.java:42) ~[org.wso2.carbon.webapp.deployer_4.11.3.jar:?]
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v80.jar:?]
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v80.jar:?]
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:153) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v80.jar:?]
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v80.jar:?]
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v80.jar:?]
        at org.apache.synapse.Axis2SynapseController.deployMediatorExtensions(Axis2SynapseController.java:785) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
        at org.apache.synapse.Axis2SynapseController.createSynapseEnvironment(Axis2SynapseController.java:403) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
        at org.apache.synapse.ServerManager.start(ServerManager.java:187) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
        at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.initESB(ServiceBusInitializer.java:371) ~[org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer_4.7.131.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.activate(ServiceBusInitializer.java:170) ~[org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer_4.7.131.jar:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_322]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_322]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_322]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_322]
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.persistence.service.InboundEndpointPersistenceServiceDSComponent.activate(InboundEndpointPersistenceServiceDSComponent.java:50) ~[org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.persistence_4.7.131.jar:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_322]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_322]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_322]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_322]
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:529) ~[org.wso2.carbon.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.removePendingItem(CarbonServerManager.java:305) ~[org.wso2.carbon.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.bundleChanged(PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.java:118) ~[org.wso2.carbon.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:973) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
...
```

I tried on window environment with same jdk 1.8 version. There is no such error.
Could you please help any suggestion?

Comment: Have the same issue between two GKE versions using wso2-am-3.1.0. It works if the node has version `1.21.9-gke.1002` or below. Starting with `1.21.10-gke.2000` it broke with above error.

Comment: @Jonathan your comment and OPs question has saved hours of effort yesterday. Thanks for the same. You can actually publish this as an answer since it works!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSO2 seems to be rather "fragile" in this area. I had the same issue on `wso2am-3.1.0` between two minor versions of GKE. It started to fail if the node ran `1.21.10-gke.2000` while it ran fine on a node running on `1.21.9-gke.1002`.

Comparing the two versions of COS and all in between this is the diff:

- Fixed a privilege escalation vulnerability in fs_context in the Linux kernel. This resolves CVE-2022-0185.
- sysctl changes: fs.file-max: 814342 -> 814343
- fixed CVE-2022-0492 in the Linux kernel.
- fixed CVE-2022-23648 in containerd.
- fixed CVE-2022-0847 in the Linux kernel.

Nothing of this seems to be relevant to WSO2. I also found [this](https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/4419) old issue, which seems to be dead.

Solutions I've found for the issue on GKE:

- Downgrade to `1.21.9-gke.1002`
- Upgrade to `1.21.11-gke.900`

Why does that help? No, clue. But it might be worth trying updates on your Centos system, especially Kernel updates.

Comment: Thanks, this has worked for us as well. No amount of rebuild and re-install helped!

Comment: Yes. I changed ubuntu 20 kernel version 5.4.0-84-generic. It works.